# Calculate field of increasing number for each unique value in another field using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.
I have a point layer, for which I need to calculate a unique increasing number. I am trying to calculate a field "BlockUnique" with a sequential number sequence (1, 2, 3, and so on). I have another field "BlockID". I need the BlockUnique field to calculate the increasing number sequence and restart for every unique BlockID. An example below.

Is this able to be done without Python?

If python is required, how would I script this?

I am not even sure where to begin!

Example: BlockID on left, BlockUnique on right.

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
C 1
D 1
D 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numbering like values in new attribute table field using field calculator of ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387622/numbering-like-values-in-new-attribute-table-field-using-field-calculator-of-arc)

Comment: Unfortunately not, i need the numbers to continue for the same letter.

Comment: Ahh, right.  I feel like that question has also come up but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class

Comment: On a side not, ArcGIS Pro 2.3 was retired by Esri on Jan. 01, 2022; so I suggest upgrading to a supported version if not the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

If we frame it another way, you basically want `BlockUnique` to be the number of occurrences of `BlockID` seen up to the current row.

Code block:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(int)


def get_id(value):
    lookup[value] += 1
    return lookup[value]
```

Expression:

```
get_id(!BlockID!)
```

Comment: I love `defaultdict` but I really dislike `global`.  Fortunately in this case `global` isn't needed because Python dictionaries are mutable so they are passed by reference, which makes the global/local namespace issue moot when updating contents of the variable.

Comment: Good call, edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation to mikewatt's answer and uses the same logic suggested by FelixIP's link.

*Code block*

```py
lookup = {}
def get_id(value):
   lookup[value] = lookup.get(value, 0) + 1
   return lookup[value]
```

*Expression*

```
get_id(!BlockID!)
```